# Power Apps and Excel

Tags: powerapps

slightly weird request although I am fairly certain Power Apps is very capable I am just not seeing it at the moment.

I want the ability for the users to search in the TextInput for example "4993"

when they hit the search button, I want my label to show data from the same spreadsheet but a different column.

Hopefully this example below will help clear anything up.

Data Source:

[image: example Data Source]

So the user will search "4993" which is in column 2 but I want my label to display the corresponding column 1 data.

They search "4993" and the label displays "SW11111"

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: could you please add screenshot of your app, especially where you search and where do you show data, do you search on table?

Comment: Hi AnkUser, Apologies for being so late a responding! (im new here) I have managed to figure this out by filtering etc however I am coming up against limits of Power Apps only being able to load in 2000 rows and now require a delegable data source such as MySQL to complete this Application.